# React siblings 'listen' to state change of each other

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a birth date validation. I have three selects: year, month, day. All part of a parent Form. So, if the selected year is startYear, then month can be only <= current month. Similar logic should exist for the day.

As I understand, I have to pass selected from child to parent, and then from parent to another child. But I am new to react and I get lost in this logic.

My birthMonth component should be able to console.log the selected year basically. From there on I can manage.

Here is the sandbox: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-villani-lbq22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find that out. I'd need to manage state in a parent, in my case it's Form.js:

```
// Validations for birth date selects

  const today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).split('-')
  
  const years = []
  const yearNow = Number(today[0])
  const startYear = (yearNow - 18)
  const endYear = (startYear - 60)

  
  for (let name = startYear; name >= endYear; name--) {
    years.push({name});
  }
  
  const [selectedYear, setSelected] = useState(years[0])
```

And then pass this all to a child and the selected state to the sibling:

```
< SelectBirthYear startYear={startYear} endYear={endYear} years={years} value={selectedYear} onChange={setSelected}/>

< SelectBirthMonth today={today} startYear={startYear} selectedYear={selectedYear}/>
```

If there is a better cleaner way, please share.